# Implementing custom Gtkmm widget: what should I return in the virtual on_* functions?

Tags: c++, widget, virtual, gtkmm

What should I return when overriding 
`virtual bool Gtk::Widget::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)` of Gtk::Widget? The documentation doesn't say anything about that at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the [C documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw) doesn't say anything either. You should report this oversight as a bug on bugzilla.gnome.org.

Perhaps it is the same as other event signals in GTK? That is, return `TRUE` to stop other handlers being invoked, `FALSE` to propagate the event further? Even though it's not an event signal, its predecessor in GTK 2 was, perhaps it's for backwards compatibility? A quick glance at the source code of `GtkButton`, for example, shows that it simply returns `FALSE`.

Comment: I was trying to find where they say that as well. I think in the java-gnome docs, they say return true for X and false for Y, but I couldn't find that in the c++ or c bindings. They really should add this to the docs.

Comment: Report a bug, then they probably will.